# how evaluate an arithmetic expression within a SQL scalar function

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions, arithmetic-expressions

i am trying to execute this scalar function and i tried a lot of approaches to achieve this but i get stuck

```
Create FUNCTION CalculateElementFunc()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ResultVar  numeric(18,6)
    DECLARE  @eq nvarchar(MAX)
    set @eq = '7.5/100*1258.236'    

    declare @expression nvarchar(max)
    set @expression = @eq

    declare @result int
    declare @SQLString nvarchar(max)
    Set @SQLString = N'Select @result = @expression'

    exec sp_executesql @SQLString, N'@expression nvarchar(100)', 
           @expression, 
           @result = @result output

    select @ResultVar = @result

    if( @ResultVar <> ROUND( @ResultVar, 2 ,1))
    set @ResultVar =  cast( ROUND( @ResultVar, 2 ,1) + .01 as numeric(18,2))

    RETURN @ResultVar
END
```

When i try to execute it

select dbo.CalculateElementFunc()

i get this error

Msg 557, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

Please Advice

Comment: Functions in T-SQL cannot have side effects. As a result you cannot insert/update or call stored procedures. Unless you implement the expression parser yourself (certainly non-trivial), I don't think this is possible in pure TSQL. Besides, performance would be horrible. You could perhaps use a CLR function to do that.

Comment: then .. what is the alternative to evaluate an arithmetic expression within a SQL scalar function

Comment: Like I said (and others pointed out too) if the expression is unknown at design time, and you need a function (not a stored procedure), your only option is CLR functions (or better yet: don't do it in SQL)

Comment: i dont know how to use CLR functions to achieve this ..     set @ eq = '7.5/100*1258.236'    i want to just evaluate the variable @ eq

Comment: Then read up on CLR functions in SQL Books online. In short: CLR functions are written in any .NET CLR supported language (typically C#) and the resulting assembly is embeded in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Limitations on SQL User Defined Functions:**

1. Non-deterministic build in functions cannot be used in user defined functions. e.g. GETDATE() or RAND().
2. XML data type is not supported.
3. Dynamic SQL queries are not allowed.
4. User defined functions does not support any DML statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) unless it is performed on Table Variable.
5. **We cannot make a call to the stored procedure.** Only extended stored procedure can be called from function.
6. We cannot create Temporary tables inside UDFs.
7. It does not support Error Handling inside UDF. Although, we can handle errors (RAISEERROR, TRY-CATCH) for the statements which uses this function.

And it looks like you are using/calling a stored procedure inside your User Defined Function. It is not the expression that's bugging you, it's that stored procedure call.

Try to replace it with some logic to achieve your desired output.

Hope this is helpful. If it helps to solve your problem then don't forget to mark it as an answer.

Comment: then .. what is the alternative to evaluate an arithmetic expression within a SQL scalar function

Comment: @SachinA: Are you sure about #1? Non-deterministic functions are prerfectly fine in UDF AFAIK. It is just that they make the UDF non-deterministic as well.

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis: Yes, non deterministic built in function will work properly, but every time you execute your user defined function -- the non deterministic build in function will give you different output (every single time). And I don't think its a reliable to use.

Comment: This is not a limitation of UDF though. It is just common sense: if you use non-deterministic built-in functions your UDF will be non-deterministic as well. And there are plenty of cases where that is OK or even desirable (e.g. `SELECT id, Name, dbo.Age(DateOfBirth) from Person`)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not recommended in SQL Server. First, it is really hard. As you have learned, a SQL Server function cannot execute dynamic SQL.

This is subtly in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql#limitations-and-restrictions):

> EXECUTE statements calling extended stored procedures.

`exec` and `sp_executesql` are not extended stored procedures.

What can you do?  Here are some options:

1. Is a stored procedure instead of a UDF a possibility? Stored procedures can execute the dynamic SQL.
2. Can you get around the problem of expression evaluation? Perhaps dynamic SQL can be used one level up in your code.
3. You *can* execute an extended stored procedure that starts another transaction and executes the dynamic SQL. Think: really bad performance.
4. You can write a CLR extended function.

Comment: no way  to evaluate an arithmetic expression within a SQL scalar function ??

Comment: @Mariam . . . You can write a CLR function or use execute an extended stored procedure.  There is no easy way.